# Как создавать уведомления не снизу, а сверху используя toastify во vue 3?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vue3, toast

Я хочу использовать библиотеку toasify в vue 3, но мне нужно чтобы карточки появлялись сверху а не снизу. В официальной доке в примерах есть такой вариант, но кода который бы так делал, нету, что странно

```
toast(message, {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
        limit: 8,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        dangerouslyHTMLString: true,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        autoClose: 3000
    });
```

Дополнение* - Имеется в виду та позиция, где появляется новая карточка. Тое есть обратите внимание на то, где появляется новая карточка, когда уже штуки 3-4 уже появились. В обычном конфиге, новая карточка появляется снизу, мне же нужно чтобы она появлялась сверху

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается есть специальное свойство для этого - **newestOnTop**, в документации этого свойства почему то нет, если у вас есть такая же задача какая была у меня, это то что нужно

Мой итоговый конфиг для дефолтоного уведомления, вдруг кому понадобиться -

```
toast(message, {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        dangerouslyHTMLString: true,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        autoClose: 3000,
        newestOnTop: true
    });
```

Удачи вам и больше хороших и полных документаций)

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы уведомления появлялись сверху, вам нужно установить опцию `position` в `toast` на значение `top`.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Toast from 'vue-toastification'
import 'vue-toastification/dist/index.css'

const toastOptions = {
  position: 'top',
  // другие опции
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Toast, toastOptions)
app.mount('#app')
```

Изучайте документацию: [vue-toastification.maronato.dev](https://vue-toastification.maronato.dev/)

Comment: Я имею в виду, не позицию где отображаются все карточки. А именно ту позицию где появляется новая карточка. Тое есть обратите внимание на то, где появляется новая карточка, когда уже штуки 3-4 уже появились. В обычном конфиге, новая карточка появляется снизу, мне же нужно чтобы она появлялась сверху, думаю добавлю мой конфиг в описание задачи, возможно это поможет

Comment: Всегда формулируйте вопрос максимально понятно, так, чтобы его понял даже не знакомый с темой вопроса человек. Прилагайте необходимый код, чтобы лучше понять вопрос.

Comment: Да, судя по всему я не совсем точно описал вопрос, прошу прощения